# How do you get and storage data from the usage details api using powershell in azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, rest

A bit farther along now.

I've done the following:

1. Set up an app registration in Azure.
2. use a get request to query the usage details api using thunder client.

I am now trying to put this into a powershell script.
I get a "Cannnot bind parameter Uri" error with my invoke-restmethod.
I have successfully gotten my access token and this is the next step I am stuck at.

```
$Param = @{
   Method = 'Get'
   Uri = "https://management.azure.com/______/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?..."
   Body = @{
         Authorization = $AccessToken
   }
}

$Execute = Invoke-RestMethod $Param
```

Help?

Edit: changed Invoke-RestMethod $Param to @Param with a new error: code Authentication failed authorization header missing.

Comment: Change `Invoke-RestMethod $Param` to `Invoke-RestMethod @Param`

Comment: damn, didn't catch that, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Body should be Headers. Access Token Variable should have Bearer in front of it when using https://management.azure.com.